# I need suggestion for using a .htaccess in Code Igniter framework

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

My old website doesn't use a framework and the .htaccess worked fine, take a look at my .htaccess code below:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\.html solution.php?solution=$1 [L]
```

So the point there is that if it detects '.html' in the url, then the user is redirected to a PHP page passing any GET parameter.

Recently, I have converted my website to use the code igniter framework, so I have converted my .htaccess code to something below:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\.html index.php/solution/index/$1 [L]
```

I end up getting a page not found. However, if I still manually type

```
http://myhost/index.php/solution/index/xxx
```

then it works, but if I type

```
http://myhost/xxx.html
```

then it doesn't. My objective here is to maintain the original URL because it is indexed by Google and I do not want the previous visitors of my website to be getting a 'page not found' for my old links.

I need a fix or suggestion that might help. Looking forward to your response. Thanks.

Comment: Actually if you want to load a page which is been coded in codeigniter you have to follow the standard like www.myhost.com/class/method so you cannot simply do www.myhost.com/xxx.html. Sorry if you already familiar with this. And also .htaccess primary objective(In most cases) is to CLEAN the url i.e to hide index.php from the url.

Comment: Actually Shomz answer is right, I removed the index.php through a .htaccess file and then I used the 'routes.php' of Code Igniter to do the redirection. Everything works fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you missed a lot of stuff while converting your website to use CI. Read about [URL suffixes](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html) and also note you can use [routes](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html) to redirect anything you can't handle normally using controllers.

You also need to modify your .htaccess to get rid of `index.php` since only modifying the config file won't work - there are a lot of resources about that, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5524648/codeigniter-htaccess).

Answer (score 0):

Follow the codeigniter user guide: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html

Specially in following section:

1. Removing the index.php file
2. Adding a URL Suffix

If still having problem then check this wiki:

> https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/Removing-index.php-in-codeigniter-xampp-for-windows

or

> [How do I write a .htaccess file to make CodeIgniters URL routing work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397014/how-do-i-write-a-htaccess-file-to-make-codeigniters-url-routing-work)