# Redirection in Codeigniter when index.php entered in URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

I created a CodeIgniter 3 application and I'm trying to redirect all the URLs with index.php to URLs without it.

My .htaccess is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/?$1 [L,QSA]
```

I'm facing the problem that both the URLs with and without index.php are redirecting on the same page. For example:

https://www.example.com/  and  https://www.example.com/index.php

redirecting to the same page.

Also, when I try to apply the index.php on sub-routes like https://www.example.com/index.php/abc, javascript doesn't load.

*I've followed this answer but doesn't work in my case: [Redirect index.php in CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861650/redirect-index-php-in-codeigniter)*

Thank you

Comment: Your `.htaccess`/mod_rewrite directives rewrite the request to `index.php/?<url>` (a single slash for path-info and the requested URL contained in the query string). However, your example `/index.php/abc` passes the URL as path-info only, no query string? So, which is it? Both? Or more? eg. `/index.php?abc`, `/index.php/?abc`, `/index.php/abc`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your htaccess with this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Always give explanation to your answers.